# Pool setup on OSX for testing

Tags: mining-pools, mining-pool-setup

I have built a pool on debian and amazon's redhat. However I'm dealing with a problem compiling the "Cryptonote-Util" npm package. Getting some pecualiar errors like:

`no memember named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std'` - Appears to be a problem with the `<memory>` library include, so I put a conditional check for it to use `<tr1/memory>` per google. That resolved that.

So then I get a new one `cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti` which I then tried a whole slew of changes to the build.gyp file for it.

I also tried installing gcc49 via brew but got a little concerned that I might break xcode which I tend to fumble around in to build iOS apps on from time to time.

I have latest nodejs/npm and brew packages on sierra.

Thanks!